What is the fastest way to texture all of these keys?
For an school project I have to make 5 products full textured and detailed.
Since it doesn't have to be game optimized I choose for individual keys on the laptop.
Having to texture them all 1 by 1 will take very very long.

So my question is: "What would be a faster way to do this?"
Edit: (Forgot img)

Hello, do you need one texture per key, or all have the same texture, and do you need to put the letter on each key?

@moonboots All keys different letter. same texture.

Possibly related (at least, for the letter-keys) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287715/35559

You could unwrap all the top faces apart from the rest (with the Project from View mode, once done invert the selection, unwrap and put the rest of the UVs over a transparent part of your image), and place the UVs on a picture with all the letters on a transparent background, mix the Image Texture with a background color in a Color > Mix Color node, and maybe add a bit of bump?

